# Create user role based on email

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello guys i have a MERN stack project, in this project user can register, login, and do some CRUD operations.

I want to make user role based on user email after they register. If the user register with email `example@bsi.com` i want to make that user role as `admin`, but if the user login with `example@gmail.com` the user role is `User`. How do i do that, i already tried but im getting error 500.

Or is there another way/logic of implementing this ?

index.js :

```
app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    bcrypt
    .hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then((hashedPassword) => {
      // create a new user instance and collect the data
      const user = new UserModel({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: hashedPassword,
        role : {$cond : {if : {email : {$regex : "bsi"}}, then : "Admin", else : "User"}}
      });
      // save the new user
      user
        .save()
        // return success if the new user is added to the database successfully
        .then((result) => {
          res.status(201).send({
            message: "User Created Successfully",
            result,
          });
        })
        // catch error if the new user wasn't added successfully to the database
        .catch((error) => {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: "Error creating user",
            error,
          });
        });
    })
    // catch error if the password hash isn't successful
    .catch((e) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: "Password was not hashed successfully",
        e,
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Before this code goes to production, you should definitely check your RegExp again. Otherwise users can add a mail like `bsi@wrongdomain.com` and get Admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `mongoose` constructor supports `$cond`, try to check the condition via code:

```
const role = new RegExp('bsi', 'gi').test(req.body.email) ? 'Admin' : 'User';
const user = new UserModel({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hashedPassword,
    role
});
```

Comment: i want to ask, is `gi` neccesarry or is it the same as `bsi`(find the similiar text)

Comment: RegExp modifiers are never generally "necessary", but depend on your actual use case. Since you are using `test` and not `match`, the modifier `g` (global) can be omitted. The modifier `i` (case insensitiv) should be set, since mail domains are case insensitive. This way "bsi", "Bsi", "BSI", etc,. will also result in a successful test.